# Photo source from facebook wall

Tags: php, facebook

i am trying to grab the photos that are being posted to the wall of this page.
Below are my codes:

```
include_once 'facebook.php';
include_once 'config.php';
require 'DropboxUploader.php';

$feed = $facebook->api('/me/feed');
foreach($feed['data'] as $feeds)
{
        if(!$feeds["object_id"]==null)
        {
        echo "Feeds secion", "<br />";
        echo $feeds["picture"], "<br />";
        echo "<img src='{$feeds['picture']}' />", "<br />";
        //echo "This is feed object_id ".$feeds["object_id"], "<br />";
        echo "This is feed id ".$feeds["id"], "<br />";
        $target_path = "uploads/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename($feeds["picture"]);

        $content = file_get_contents($feeds["source"]);
        file_put_contents($target_path, $content);

        $uploader = new DropboxUploader('testing@hotmail.com', 'testing');
        $uploader->upload($target_path, 'imageStore');

        }


}
```

I was able to grab the picture which was the thumbnail of that image. I would like to ask how i could grab the actual photo source itself instead of the thumbnail.

Please advice me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some trying and checking, i guess there is no way i could grab the actual photo from facebook wall as they are all preview thumbnails.

I went into another approach on this matter.
When a photo is posted onto the wall, faceboook will automatically creates(if folder does not exist) a album "Wall Photos" and place the photos inside.
I uses this theory to grab the album id and all the photos inside.

```
$album = $facebook->api('/'.$app_id.'/albums');
foreach($album['data'] as $photo)
{
    if($photo['name']=="Wall Photos")
    {
        $image = $facebook->api('/'.$photo['id'].'/photos');
        photoGrab($image); //function
    }
}//each of $album foreach
```

It is not a very ideal way thought.
Please advise me if there is any better and efficient ways.

Thank you!

Comment: This only works if the photo was posted to the wall by the creator itself.